# Does upgrading GCM preserve the current API Key in use?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am upgrading a project that has an older version of GCM (7.5) to the latest version of GCM (9.2). The current project already has a server API key and that key is in use to send push notifications to current users of the app. My specific question is if we generate the JSON configuration file for the current app with it re-create(create a new API key) or over-write the current API key we have in use? We would like to avoid having to do that if possible.

Thank you in advance for any clarity that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced upgrading a lower version of GCM to a higher version, but to test this out, I tried importing a Google Project to the Firebase Console (so its like GCM to FCM), keeping in check the current Server Key.

After successfully importing the project to Firebase, the Server Key from before is retained, and can be seen being used in the Firebase Console. So I think the same behavior can also be expected when upgrading a lower GCM version to a higher version.

I also don't see why the Server API key would re-generate if the GCM project is upgraded.

Though I'm not entirely sure. Hope this helps somehow. Cheers!